# Remove Entry widgets created in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am now making a GUI application with tkinter and whatever number I put in the uppermost box, the GUI will automatically add another [entry row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGxKa.png)

When I put 1, and then I try to bigger number such as 3 or 5 it works just fine ,the entry row will show up, the problem is whenever I put number such as 5 and the try to put number less than 5, the entry will still show up instead of 
[removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSBFp.png)

Is there any way that when I put bigger number such as 4 and followed by the less such as 2 and the, the entry from 5 will be removed??

Edit : add code

```
def choiceone(self):
    self.labeln1 = ttk.Label(self, text="1", justify="center")
    self.labeln1.grid(row=7, column=1)

    self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry1.grid(row=7, column=2)

    self.entry2 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry2.grid(row=7, column=3)

    self.entry3 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry3.grid(row=7, column=4)

    self.entry4 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry4.grid(row=7, column=5)


def choicetwo(self):
    self.labeln2 = ttk.Label(self, text="2", justify="center")
    self.labeln2.grid(row=9, column=1)

    self.entry5 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry5.grid(row=9, column=2)

    self.entry6 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry6.grid(row=9, column=3)

    self.entry7 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry7.grid(row=9, column=4)

    self.entry8 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry8.grid(row=9, column=5)


def choicethree(self):
    self.labeln3 = ttk.Label(self, text="3", justify="center")
    self.labeln3.grid(row=11, column=1)

    self.entry9 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry9.grid(row=11, column=2)

    self.entry10 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry10.grid(row=11, column=3)

    self.entry11 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry11.grid(row=11, column=4)

    self.entry12 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.entry12.grid(row=11, column=5)


class MultiLevel(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Fatigue Failure", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        labele1 = ttk.Label(self, text="METHOD 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        labele1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        ttk.Separator(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL).grid(row=2, columnspan=5,   sticky="EW")

        labele0 = ttk.Label(self, text="")
        labele0.grid(row=3, column=1)

        label0 = ttk.Label(self, text="Number of \nStress Level: ", font=MEDIUM_FONT, justify="center")
        label0.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.entry0 = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.entry0.grid(row=4, column=2)

        button0 = ttk.Button(self, text="OK ", command=lambda: self.ok())
        button0.grid(row=4, column=3)

    def ok(self):
        try:
            float(self.entry0.get())

        except ValueError:
            errormsg("INPUT YOUR NUMBER")

        else:
            if float(self.entry0.get()) == 1:
            choiceone(self)

        elif float(self.entry0.get()) == 2:
            choiceone(self)
            choicetwo(self)

        elif float(self.entry0.get()) == 3:
            choiceone(self)
            choicetwo(self)
            choicethree(self)
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not post your code.

Comment: thanks, I've added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @furas said, you need to destroy the existing widgets first:

```
def ok(self):
    try:
        float(self.entry0.get())

    except ValueError:
        errormsg("INPUT YOUR NUMBER")

    else:
        # remove existing widgets start from row 7
        for widget in self.grid_slaves():
            if int(widget.grid_info()["row"]) >= 7:
                widget.destroy()

        if float(self.entry0.get()) == 1:
            choiceone(self)
        ...
```

PS: As from your code, the concern widgets are put in row 7 and above.

The suggestion is based on your code, but I think you better refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you put numer you alway create new Entries in grid but you never remove previous Entries so don't expect that they will magically disappear.

You have to use `grid_forget()` to hide widget (but not remove from memory), or `grid_remove()` to remove from grid and from memory.

Now when you put 1 then you create entries in first row, and when you put 3 you create again entries in first row so you have two entries in every cell in first row - one above another - previous entries don't disappear.

BTW: It could be easier if you would keep entries on list - `self.entries[0]`, `self.entries[1]`, etc. or as 2-dimensional list `self.entries[row][col]`.

Comment: Both `grid_forget()` and `grid_remove()` will not destroy the widget.  They both just remove the widget from the grid.  `grid_remove()` will keep the grid information of the widget and later just call `grid()` to put back the widget to the same position in the grid as before.  `grid_forget()` will `forget` the grid information.

Comment: Cool I've actually tried grid_forget() and it works, thanks a lot....

    BTW, what do you mean by keeping my entries on the list??